# Splitting a streaming hexadecimal string into smaller chunks

Tags: c#, string, split, serial-port

I have a stream of hex data coming from a serial device, in this format:

```
F4 01 09 05 05 F4 01 09 05 05 F4 F 01 09 05 05 F4 01 09 05 05
```

What I need to do (in C#) is read the incoming string, and split it into chunks at 'F4', for processing. So that I get:

```
string DataToProcess = "F4 01 09 05 05";
```

that updates as every section comes in.

I am a bit stuck as to the best way to approach this.

I have:

```
byte[] data = new byte[count];
 _serialPort.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

string rawString = BitConverter.ToString(data, 0);

if (rawString.Contains("F4"))
{
     //split here?                    
}
```

As it is a live stream, the `count` variable is always changing. How can I 'wait' for an `F4`, and create a substring from a section?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the "F4" substring always the same length or does the number of bytes from one F4 to the other vary as well?

Comment: It is the same length. But the stream may not start at an F4.

Comment: I'll assume the data is being read within a loop. And the next iteration starts where the previous one ends. So the Read function returns the number ob bytes read which can tell you how many substrings there are, the rest of the bytes (which is less than the length of the F4 substring) should be saved and added to the beginning of the data array in the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest grouping `data`, *without converting* the array into string

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {
    0xF4, 0x01, 0x09, 0x05, 0x05, ..., 0x09, 0x05, 0x05 };

// Using side effect in not the best practice, but helpful
int group = 0;

var result = data
  .GroupBy(item => item == 0xF4 ? ++group : group)
  .Select(chunk => chunk.ToArray());
//.ToArray(); // <- if you want to materialize
```

Test

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(array => string.Join(", ", array
     .Select(item => item.ToString("X2")))));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome

```
F4, 01, 09, 05, 05
F4, 01, 09, 05, 05
F4, 0F, 01, 09, 05, 05
F4, 01, 09, 05, 05
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to give me varying results. Sometimes only half a line, and sometimes more...

`report = "F4, 01, 09, 01, 05, 00, 02, 1C, A0, 06, 00, 03, A3, 40, 07, 00, 05, 29, E0, 01, 00, 00, 11, 20, 02, 00, 00, 15, 08, 13, 00, 00, 18, F0, 0C, 00, 00, 00, 00, 03, 00, 00, A3, 80, 04, 00, 00, 5C, 7F, 00\r\nF4, 01, 09, 02, 05, 00, 02, 1D, 04, 06, 00, 03, A3, A3`

Comment: @anti: if you have wrong/unexpected outcome, please, provide a *counter example*, i.e. `data = new byte[] {....};`

Comment: Sorry! Please see below: the value of `count` changes as data is read, should i be waiting for a certian number of bytes? (the stream is live as i connect, so may not begin at an `F4`.

Comment: `int count = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
                if (count > 10)
                {           byte[] data = new byte[count];
                    _serialPort.Read(data, 0, data.Length);                  
                    int group = 0;
                    var result = data.GroupBy(item => item == 0xF4 ? ++group : group)
                      .Select(chunk => chunk.ToArray());
                    string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
                      .Select(array => string.Join(", ", array
                         .Select(item => item.ToString("X2")))))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Split(string[], StringSplitOptions)` mixed with LINQ to split by each `F4`:

```
if (rawString.Contains("F4"))
{
    string[] dataToProcess = rawString.Split(new string[] { "F4" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(l => "F4" + l).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! This gives me an error:

`Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>to string[]. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add `.ToArray()`, problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a fixed-size buffer and parse data as it comes in. Something like:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
while (_serialPort.Read(data, 0, data.Length) > 0) {
    String rawString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
    String[] splitted = rawString.Split("\u00F4");
    // work with splitted
}
```

Notice that example above uses ASCII decoding instead of `BitConverter.ToString`. If you need to work with bytes instead, why convert it to a `String` in the first place? You can work with bytes as well, C# supports a syntax like `0xF4`, that would represent a number in hex format.